# Get Date Object In UTC format in Java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have written following code. I want to get Date object in UTC format.

I am able to get expected date string in UTC using `SimpleDateFormat`. But using same `SimpleDateFormat` object, I am not able to get object in UTC format. It is returning object with IST format.

After searching, I found that Date object doesn't store timestamp info.

How can I get date object in UTC format ?

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class dddd {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Input - "+1393572325000L);
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date= new Date(1393572325000L);  
        String dateString = formatter.format(date);

        System.out.println("Converted UTC TIME (using Format method) : "+dateString);

        Date date2 =null;
        try {
            date2 = formatter.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("Parsed Date Object (using Parse method) : "+date2);

        System.out.println("Expected Date Object : Fri Feb 28 07:25:25 UTC 2014");

    }

}
```

This prints following output :

```
Input - 1393572325000
Converted UTC TIME (using Format method) : 2014-02-28 07:25:25
Parsed Date Object (using Parse method) : Fri Feb 28 12:55:25 IST 2014
Expected Date Object : Fri Feb 28 07:25:25 UTC 2014
```

Comment: short and simple `Instant.now.toString()`

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 85):

```
final Date currentTime = new Date();
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println("UTC time: " + sdf.format(currentTime));
```

Comment: This I have already done.This will return date represented in string format which I am getting. I want to get Date object not string.

Comment: @user2745792 You say you want to get a "Date object not a string". But you got a Date object on the 4th line of your `main` method.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 23):

A Date doesn't have any time zone. What you're seeing is only the formatting of the date by the `Date.toString()` method, which uses your local timezone, always, to transform the timezone-agnostic date into a String that you can understand.

If you want to display the timezone-agnostic date as a string using the UTC timezone, then use a SimpleDateFormat with the UTC timezone (as you're already doing in your question).

In other terms, the timezone is not a property of the date. It's a property of the format used to transform the date into a string.

Comment: I am getting date string in UTC format.So there no way to get Date object in UTC format?

Comment: No. A Date doesn't have a timezone. It doesn't have a format either. A Date is just a wrapper around a `long`, representing a number of milliseconds.

Answer (score 18):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli ( 1_393_572_325_000L )
       .toString()
```

> 2014-02-28T07:25:25Z

## Details

(a) You seem be confused as to what a Date is. As the [answer by JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22091222/642706) said, a Date tracks the number of milliseconds since the [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) (first moment of 1970) in the [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone (that is, with no time zone offset). So a Date has no time zone<sup>†</sup>. And it has no "format". We create string representations *from* a Date's value, but the **Date itself is not a String and has no String**.

(b) You refer to a "UTC format". UTC is not a format, not I have heard of. [UTC (Coordinated Universal Time)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is the origin point of time zones. Time zones east of the Royal Observatory in Greenwich, London are some number of hours & minutes ahead of UTC. Westward time zones are behind UTC.

You seem to be referring to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted strings. You are using the optional format, omitting (1) the `T` from the middle, and (2) the offset-from-UTC at the end. Unless presenting the string to a user in the user interface of your app, I suggest you generally stick with the usual format:

- `2014-02-27T23:03:14+05:30`
- `2014-02-27T23:03:14Z` ('Z' for Zulu, or UTC, with an offset of +00:00)

(c) Avoid the 3 or 4 letter time zone codes. They are neither standardized nor unique. "IST" for example can mean either *Indian Standard Time* or *Irish Standard Time*.

(d) Put some effort into searching StackOverflow before posting. You would have found all your answers.

(e) Avoid the java.util.Date & Calendar classes bundled with Java. They are notoriously troublesome. Use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or Java 8’s new java.time package (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

## java.time

The java.time classes use standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing and generating strings.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2014-02-27T23:03:14+05:30" ); 
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2014-02-27T23:03:14Z" );
```

Parse your count of milliseconds since the epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli ( 1_393_572_325_000L );
```

> instant.toString(): 2014-02-28T07:25:25Z

Adjust that `Instant` into a desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2014-02-28T02:25:25-05:00[America/Montreal]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) uses ISO 8601 as its defaults.

A Joda-Time `DateTime` object knows its on assigned time zone, unlike a java.util.Date object.

Generally better to specify a time zone explicitly rather than rely on default time zone.

### Example Code

```
long input = 1393572325000L;
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( input, DateTimeZone.UTC );

DateTimeZone timeZoneIndia = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTimeZone timeZoneIreland = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Dublin" );

DateTime dateTimeIndia = dateTimeUtc.withZone( timeZoneIndia );
DateTime dateTimeIreland = dateTimeIndia.withZone( timeZoneIreland );

// Use a formatter to create a String representation. The formatter can adjust time zone if you so desire.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FM" ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
String output = formatter.print( dateTimeIreland );
```

Dump to console…

```
// All three of these date-time objects represent the *same* moment in the timeline of the Universe.
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeIndia: " + dateTimeIndia );
System.out.println( "dateTimeIreland: " + dateTimeIreland );

System.out.println( "output for Montréal: " + output );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeUtc: 2014-02-28T07:25:25.000Z
dateTimeIndia: 2014-02-28T12:55:25.000+05:30
dateTimeIreland: 2014-02-28T07:25:25.000Z
output for Montréal: vendredi 28 février 2014 02:25:25
```

---

<sup>†</sup> Actually, java.util.Date *does* have a time zone. That time zone is assigned deep in its source code. Yet the class ignores that time zone for most practical purposes. And its `toString` method applies the JVM’s current default time zone rather than that internal time zone. Confusing? Yes. This is one of many reasons to avoid the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. Use java.time and/or Joda-Time instead.

Answer (score 7):

In java 8 , It's really easy to get timestamp in UTC by using ***java 8 java.time.Instant*** library :

```
Instant.now();
```

That few word of code will return the UTC Timestamp.

Comment: Does not address the Question, which has an input of `1393572325000L`. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22101948/642706) for full code parsing this input.

Answer (score 3):

You can subtract the time zone difference from now.

```
final Calendar calendar  = Calendar.getInstance();
final int      utcOffset = calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + calendar.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
final long     tempDate  = new Date().getTime();

return new Date(tempDate - utcOffset);
```