# how to retrieve exact dates as stored in mongodb using java driver

Tags: mongodb, date, mongo-java-driver

Here are the sample data in my sales collection, how to retrieve the exact date as stored in date field in the sample sales collection :

```
   /* 1 */
   {
     "_id" : ObjectId("5a4e591efce077c4d7e6f523"),
     "date" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
     "name" : "testing 123"
    }

    /* 2 */
  {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5a4e591efce077c4d7e6f524"),
       "date" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:01.000Z"),
       "name" : "Testing 231"
      }

   /* 3 */
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a4e591efce077c4d7e6f525"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-01T23:59:59.000Z"),
     "name" : "teSting 456"
  }
```

Here is my java code :

```
  import com.mongodb.BasicDBList;
  import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
   import com.mongodb.DB;
       import com.mongodb.Mongo;
     import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
     import com.mongodb.CommandResult;
     import org.bson.types.BasicBSONList;

   public class MongoTest {

public static void main(String[] s) throws Exception {
    Mongo mongo = new MongoClient("localhost");
    DB db = new DB(mongo, "onixtest");
    BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject("find", "sales");


    CommandResult commandResult = db.command(obj);
    BasicDBObject o = (BasicDBObject) commandResult.get("cursor");        
    BasicDBList o1 = (BasicDBList) o.get("firstBatch");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
    //System.out.println(o1);
    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
    for(Object o11  : o1)
    System.out.println(((BasicDBObject)o11).get("date"));

    mongo.close();

}}
```

Here is the output of running the above java program:

```
   Sun Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 2017
   Sun Jan 01 05:30:01 IST 2017
   Mon Jan 02 05:29:59 IST 2017
```

Regards
kris

Comment: java.util.Date prints the output in local time but the value is stored is same as what you have in db. For formatting needs you can use `SimpleDataFormat` with timezone set to  UTC to see what you have in db.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Date Object In UTC format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091107/get-date-object-in-utc-format-in-java)