# How to pass DateTime with UTC and CDT time zones

Tags: java, rest, datetime, utc

I have Rest API which will accept date time in URI it works fine except for UTC.

I have the following code which will format the DateTime and outputs the result, when I use CDT, EST, PDT,PST etc, but I want the date format to also accept UTC time zone along with all other. Client can send the date time in any format(UTC mostly, but also includes CDT,EST) and I need to pass it as is, it is client's choice what time zone to pass

```
Date now = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat inStr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmz")
```

This works for CDT, EST,PDT but not for UTC I want to include UTC aswell in the rest API call get the desired output.

Can some one please help me on this

Valid values are - 2018-07-11T20:30UTC , 2018-07-11T18:30CDT

Comment: I don't like the idea of storing different timezones in your database.  I think you should store all timestamps in a single timezone, and usually UTC is the one used.  This way, it is the client's responsibility to worry about how to render a given timestamp (and the client would know it's own timezone, whereas the server might not).

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - i am not storing the time zones in DB, I need to parse(UTC, CDT etc) what ever the client sends to me

Comment: As of now the CDT, EST all other time zones work, but UTC doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Date Object In UTC format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091107/get-date-object-in-utc-format-in-java)

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - Thanks Tim. But this will not work, I cannot explicitly set the time, it comes from client, it might be UTC or CDT or any other. I need to pass all time zones

Comment: How are you parsing the incoming timestamp?  Note that a Java `Date` has no timezone, it is just a point in time.

Comment: Im using the following code to pass the incoming timestamp

Date now = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat inStr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmz")


The above code pass time zones CDT, PST etc but not UTC

Comment: Your code works fine for me, and accepts UTC.  Are you sure you haven't made a mistake?

Comment: @Dawood - yea it is not working for me with UTC. Can you please share how did you test ?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmz");
        Date test = format.parse("2018-06-14T12:34UTC");
        System.out.println(test);`

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - Actually I just need to pass the date time argument in the rest API URI. it could be CDT or UTC or any thing. it will be in the following format 2018-07-11T20:30UTC , 2018-07-11T18:30CDT
UTC is not working with SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmz") rest all works

Comment: OK, what comes in from your REST API is a different question entirely.  Use your debugger to check what the actual date string is.  If it's something like `"2018-06-14T12:34UTC"`, then your code works.

Comment: okay let me check.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: Relying on three letter time zone abbreviations seems dangerous to me. They are ambiguous, so I wouldn’t be too sure what you get. Also I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I can neither reproduce on Java 7 nor on Java 10.