# Converting string of timestamp to UTC date in android

Tags: android, date, kotlin, time

> ```
> UTC string to UTC date conversion in android
> ```

```
fun convertStringDateToDate(stDate: String, format: String, tzCode: String? = null): Date? {
       return try {
           val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat(format)
           inputFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
           return inputFormat.parse(stDate)
       } catch (e: Exception) {
           e.printStackTrace()
           null
       }
   }
```

above function parses the date string in the local timezone of the device!
Any idea how to get the UTC date

it gives as output of "Fri Dec 31 10:01:24 GMT+05:30 2021"

for input string of "2021-12-31T10:01:24Z"

Comment: This is Kotlin right?

Comment: yes, this is Kotlin

Comment: What's the `format: String` arg value you passed? Try new Java Time API (Java 8+), lots of good answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091107/get-date-object-in-utc-format-in-java

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'